# Capture class that was matched in jQuery callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to access the class that was matched by a jQuery selector in a callback function. For example, if I have the following HTML,

```
<p class="someclass sorted-1 anotherclass">test</p>
```

I'd like to match this element and get the `sorted-1` class name. The value `1` is arbitrary. Something like the following. `getMatchedClass()` is pseudo code. I thought I could get the value from `$(this)`, but I'm not seeing it.

```
$('[class*=sorted-]').on('click', function() {
    var className = getMatchedClass();
    console.log(className); // should output 'sorted-1'
});
```

Does anyone know if this is possible? I'm having a hard time coming up with search terms. I keep getting results on selected values which isn't what I want.

Thanks

**Update**

Based on @maheer-ali's answer I came up with the following solution.

```
   $(function() {
        function column(className) {
            const regex = /sorted-([0-9]+)/;
            return className.match(regex)[0].replace(regex, '$1');
        }
        $('[class*=sorted-]').each(function(i, r) {
            // col is the dashed number after sorted
            // if parsing `sorted-42`, `col` would equal 42
            const col = column($(r).context.className);

            // Use the `col` value here.
            $(r).doSomething({ column: col });
        });
    });
```

Comment: `let p = $('p').attr("class").match(/[\w-]*sorted[\w-]*/g)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `match()` and regular expression. And get the first element of result array.

```js
$('[class*=sorted-]').on('click', function() {
    var className = this.className.match(/sorted-[0-9]+/)[0];
    console.log(className); // should output 'sorted-1'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="someclass sorted-1 anotherclass">test</p>
```

The other way is to use `split()` and `startsWith()`. `split()` the `className` by `" "` and use `find()` to get element element with `startsWith` the string `"sorted-"`

```js
$('[class*=sorted-]').on('click', function() {
    var className = this.className.split(' ').find(x => x.startsWith('sorted-'))
    console.log(className); // should output 'sorted-1'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="someclass sorted-1 anotherclass">test</p>
```

Comment: I went ahead and marked this one as the approved answer. I was trying to avoid this route, hoping jQuery would store the matched class(es), but it works. I'll update my question with the solution I came up with. Thanks @maheer-ali

Answer (score 1):

The callback function that you're passing is called with the event that triggered it.

You can access `event.target.classList` to get an array of all of the classes on that object. If you have a fixed set of class patterns you're looking for, you could search that list for the class.

Hope this helped!